# Looping a macro in excel

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I want to creat a Macro that looks down column H and selects 14 cells. It then copies them and pastes them via a "transpose paste", i.e they go from rows to columns in the next sheet. It then keeps on doing this until it has run out. This is my code so far:

```
Sub Macro5()
    '
    ' Macro5 Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
    ' Dim x as integer
    ' Dim y as integer
    ' x = 313
    ' y = x + 13
    '     Range("Hx:Hy").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    'x = x + 14
End Sub
```

It supposed to start at cell H313.

My problem is, evertime I run this it just copies whatever cell I've highlighted and pastes that in the next sheet, without selecting all the cells I want.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Rows starting with a `'` are considered a comment and are ignored by VBA. Therefore your code that selects the range (`Range("Hx:Hy").Select`) is never executed.

The first line being executed is `Selection.Copy` that - you guessed it - copies the cell you currently selected :)

Besides you need to compute the range, as `"Hx:Hy"` will never be parsed to `H313:H326`.

Use `Range("H"&x&":H"&y)` or `Range(Cells(x, 8), Cells(y, 8))`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just a few questions: When I use your range code, it gives me a compile error, why would this be happening? Also, would this then loop automatically?

Comment: Please edit your question and attach your updated code (but don't remove the original one).

Answer (score 0):

Because you've 'commented out' your first portion of code the first line actually being run is

`Selection.Copy`

Which is why it's only copying what's highlighted. I think, if you uncomment everything, you've still got a couple of issues but I think your main issue is the line:

`Range("Hx:Hy").Select`

Should be something like:

`Range("H" & CStr(x) & ":H" & CStr(y)).Select`

```
Dim x as integer
Dim y as integer

x = 313
y = x + 13

Range("H" & CStr(x) & ":H" & CStr(y)).Select

Selection.Copy

Sheets("Sheet3").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your Cstr bit but it just seems to copy the whole row H as opposed to the cells I need, why is this?